# Scheduled Task won't run in Windows 10 when started by scheduler

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task to run a .CMD script at a set time each day. The Windows 10 64 bit system (1511) was clean installed, and the task was created manually.

When the task's scheduled time is reached, it does not run. The Task Scheduler reports "The operator or administrator has refused the request (0x800710E0)"

If I run the task from within the task scheduler by right-click Run, it runs normally. Then the The Task Scheduler reports "The operation completed successfully (0x0)".

Until the next day after the schedule time. Then the task does not run, and the first error is displayed again.

The computer was not waking for the task, despite having the "Wake the computer to run this task" box checked.  I now have the BIOS wake the computer 5 minutes before the task time.

Comment: What does the CMD script contain exactly? If it references any user-level variables or profile areas, then it will probably fail when no user is logged in.  If you schedule the task to run at a time while you're watching it (so it doesn't have to try and wake the computer first), does it still fail in the same way?  If you make a basic CMD that contain something basic like `Echo Test`, and then setup/run another Task the same way, only running that basic script, does it complete successfully?

Comment: Also, is this script something that can have the task configured to run with the built-in _System_ account to avoid similar problems?

Comment: what user is the task configured to run as, and does that user have login as Batch Job permissions?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Tasks that ran perfectly fine on Windows 7 won't run on Windows 10 at all. I've updated the Author/User to have my new domain, checked all the executable paths and options, etc. Sometimes they do run and I can't tell why.